# Torsion of a group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $G[p]$ := { $ g \in G \enspace \text{such that} \enspace pg=0 $ }. Let $ Y = G/p^{t+1}G $. Then what is $ Y[p^{t}] $ in terms of $G$ $?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is half right. Here is the general answer:

> $Y[p^t] = \left.\left(G[p^t] + pG\right)\middle/p^{t+1}G\right.$

Why:

> $g \in Y[p^t] \iff p^t g \in p^{t+1} G \iff \exists h \in G:p^tg = p^{t+1}h \iff \exists h \in G: p^t(g-ph) = 0$. So if $g \in Y[p^t]$ then $g = (g-ph) + ph \in G[p^t] + pG$. Similarly, both $G[p^t]$ and $pG$ are sent by $p^t$ into $p^{t+1}G$, so we get the reverse inclusion as well.

Comment: I was going to "fix" it too (enlarging pG with the p^t torsion). Thank you for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The group $$pG/p^{t+1}G$$ is included in $Y[p^t]$ (modulo $p^{t+1}G$, elements in $pG$ get killed by $p^t$).

*Spoiler:*

> The other way, if $\hat{g}\in Y$ such that $p^t\hat{g} =\hat{0}$, then $p^t g \in p^{t+1}G$, and $p^tg = p^{t+1}h$, for some $h\in G$. So $p^t(g-ph)=0$. This is where, I should have continued by $g-ph \in G[p^t]$, which may or may not be null. Hence, as per Jack's guidance, the answer needs to be completed to $(pG+G[p^t])/p^{t+1}G$.

Comment: To be clear this isn't the correct answer, but it is half of it.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Agree. Hint only. This subgroup of $Y$ is included in $Y[p^t]$. The inverse inclusion is yet to be proven.

Comment: The other inclusion is false.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Under general group $G$? Torsion-free $G$, for example, should work.

Comment: It is true for torsion-free. It is false in general for abelian groups. For instance the cyclic group of order 2 is a counterexample with p=2, t=1.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I see, to avoid your counterexample, $p$ should not divide the order of the torsion part of $G$.